# Number of classes loaded in java

Tags: java, classloader

I have program that the number of classes loaded there is constantly rising.

How could this actually be ? Or do i misunderstand something in java about classloading?

Here is a snippet from jConsole overnight :

[alt text http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/200/classesp.jpg](http://img200.imageshack.us/img200/200/classesp.jpg)

Could someone please tell me what could be the possible reason for such a constant classloading growth ? Or is this normal ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you implemented your own `ClassLoader` of any kind?

Comment: No , not implement any classloader.
I have a j2se application based on spring.
So i guess its the context classloader and the classloader from spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sort of features does your application have that are out-of-the-ordinary as regards class loading? For example:

- are you constantly loading classes from remote sources (e.g. `RMI`)?
- are you using your own `ClassLoader`?
- are you using the Java `Proxy` mechanism to create classes on the fly?

Comment: I dont have my own classloader or constantly loading classes from remote sources , neither making use of the java proxy mechanism.

But i run inside some sort of an application server that launches me and is some kind of a black box. I guess i will have to look for the problem there.

Thanks !

Comment: So when you are running JConsole, you are running it against the AppServer? Not your app? There is a big difference!

Comment: my program is inside this "server". its the same JVM. and its like 95% of the whole program.

Comment: If i am using the Java Proxy? where could be here the problem with the classloading ?

Comment: Well, if you continually call java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance, then each proxy may end up being an instance of a different class (i.e. a new class object may be created on-the-fly) if the list of implemented interfaces is different.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a class loader leak. Read [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/classloaderlocal-how-avoid) for example.

Comment: Thanks for the link , its a great post. But i dont redeploy my application in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other profilers to know exactly what java objects are in memory (and verify that there is no memory leak) :

- List TPTP (Eclipse plugin)
- List Netbeans profiler (very good profiler)
- List JProbe profiler (not free)